# FFMPEG with php 5.3?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I was able to create thumbnail via FFMPEG when using PHP 5.2. Now, I've updated it to PHP 5.3 and the DL() function is not fully compatible. Is there a way around to load the FFMPEG extension without using the DL() function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, through php.ini. The DL function was removed because it was a pretty bad idea™. The syntax is

```
extension=your_extension.so
```

Comment: Note that you won't be able to use the same library file, though -- PHP extensions must be recompiled for each major version of PHP.

Comment: For PHP 5.3, do I leave extension=ffmpeg.so in the php.ini? After I've upgraded to PHP 5.3, Plesk automatically moved it to zend_extensions_psa.ini So I thought I did everything correctly, but I still don't see ffmpeg extension? Any clue?